# Access VBA - Passing a date variable from function to sub

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple queries that use the same date and want to ask the user only once

```
Public Sub runappends()
Dim getmyparameter As Date

Call getmyparameter1(getmyparameter)

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Append to Current Quarter Counts 1", acViewNormal, acAdd

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Append to Current Quarter Counts 2", acViewNormal, acAdd


End Sub



Public Function getmyparameter1(getmyparameter As Date)


getmyparameter = CDate(InputBox("enter date greater than"))


End Function
```

The query(s)  criteria is   `=>getparameter1()` as the only option here is to call the function.

But can't seem to get the date to pass to query 2,3, etc.?

Comment: The first part is that nstead of `Call getmyparameter1(getmyparameter)`, you have to call the function in a way that stores the value in the variable you made, `getmyparameter = getmyparameter1()`

Comment: Could you add the SQL for the two queries please.  You could use the `QueryDef.Parameter` to pass the date into the query.

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend using a `DAO.QueryDef`, rather than using the `OpenQuery` method. That will make your code a lot simpler.

I assume that your 2 queries have a date parameter. For this answer, I'll assume the parameter is called `pDate`. So you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub RunAppends()
    Dim db as DAO.Database, qdf as DAO.QueryDef
    Dim dateParam as Date

    set db = CurrentDB

    ' you can move this to a separate function if you really want,
    ' but it's only 1 line, so there's not really a reason to.
    dateParam = CDate(InputBox("Enter date:"))

    set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Append to Current Quarter Counts 1")
    qdf.Parameters("pDate").Value = dateParam
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

    set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Append to Current Quarter Counts 2")
    qdf.Parameters("pDate").Value = dateParam
    qdf.execute dbFailOnError

    ' cleanup your objects
    set qdf = Nothing
    set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Since the code to execute the 2 queries is the same, you could use a loop structure (e.g. have an array of the query names, and execute them that way).

I would also recommend changing your query names: Generally, you should avoid having spaces in your object names. You can also use Hungarian notation to clarify that these are queries---something like `qAppendToCurrentQuarterCounts1` and `qAppendToCurrentQuarterCounts2`. Then I also wonder what the difference between these 2 queries is, since they're so similarly named...

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds - was just considering giving an example of the loop structure you mention.

Comment: Even shorter: `qdf!pDate = dateParam`

Comment: Many thanks - to all.   A couple of good solutions here,  those that I didn't use,  added some knowledge to my library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
Public myparameter As Date

Public Function getmyparameter() as Date
  getmyparameter=myparameter
End Function

Public Sub setmyparameter()
  myparameter=CDate(InputBox("enter date greater than"))
End Sub
```

Use `Call setmyparameter` to ask the user for the date and `getmyparameter()` in your query criteria.